# Getting an error System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries 101

Tags: apex, error

**Please try to help regarding this error as soon as possible.**

I am getting the error:

> Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: 00516000004wlL6/00DA0000000HBcb
>
> Visualforce Page: /apex/AgencyNameVF
>
> caused by: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101
>
> Class.AgencyNameService.agencyNameUpdateAccPC: line 119, column 1
> Trigger.AgencyNameAfterTrigger: line 60, column 1

**Apex Code:**

```
public Class AgencyNameService{
  
    Set<String> updatedAgencyIds = new Set<String> ();
    List<Agency_Name__c> updatedagencyList = new List<Agency_Name__c>();
    List<Agency_Name__c> agencylistRec  = new List<Agency_Name__c>();
    Agency_Name__c agencyName = new Agency_Name__c();
    
    public AgencyNameService(Agency_Name__c newAgencyName){
        agencyName = newAgencyName;        
    }
    
    public AgencyNameService(){
    }
    
    public void getAgencyNameList(){
          //Empty check added to unnecessary avoid query call
        if (agencylistRec.isEmpty()){
        //Modified the below query to exclude Alias Names
          agencylistRec = [Select Name, Agency_Name_Type__c,Effective_Date__c,Is_Display_Name__c,New_Agency_Name__c   
                         from Agency_Name__c where Agency__c =: agencyName.Agency__c and Agency_Name_Type__c <> 'Alias'];
        }
    }
        
    //Note:Assuming there is no bulk insertion of Agency Name records
    public void UncheckAllrecords(){
        getAgencyNameList();
        
        for(Agency_Name__c agencyuse : agencylistRec){
            System.debug('kanhu ** '+agencyName.ID +' - '+ agencyuse.ID);
             if(agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c && agencyName.ID != agencyuse.ID){
                 agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c = false;
                 system.debug('uncheck:'+agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c);
                 Update agencyuse;
             } 
        }    
    }
    
    public void CheckLegalrecord(){
        system.debug('checklegal');
        Set<String> AgencyIds = new Set<String> ();
        Agency_Name__c agencynameLegal;
        getAgencyNameList();
        for(Agency_Name__c agencyuse : agencylistRec){
            if(agencyName.Agency__r.RecordtypeName__c != System.Label.Agency_Record_Type_Nationwide){
                if(agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c)
                AgencyIds.add(agencyuse.ID);
                
              if(agencyuse.Agency_Name_Type__c.equals(System.label.AGENCY_NAME_TYPE_LEGAL))
                  agencynameLegal = agencyuse;   
            }
        }
        if(AgencyIds.isEmpty() && agencynameLegal != null){
            agencynameLegal.Is_Display_Name__c = true;
            Update agencynameLegal;
        }    

    }
    
    public void ChangePreviousLegaltoDBA(){   
        getAgencyNameList(); 
        for(Agency_Name__c agencyuse : agencylistRec){
             if(agencyName.Agency_Name_Type__c == System.Label.Agency_Name_Type_Legal && agencyName.ID != agencyuse.ID){ 
                  agencyuse.Agency_Name_Type__c = System.Label.Agency_Name_Type_DBA;
                  update agencyuse;
             }      
        }
    }

    public void updateProcessingCodeName(){
        List<Processing_Code__c> PCagencyNameList = [select Processing_Code_Name_Val__c,Processing_Code_Name__c FROM Processing_Code__c WHERE Processing_Code_Name__c = : agencyName.ID];
       
        for(Processing_Code__c PCRec : PCagencyNameList){
            PCRec.Processing_Code_Name_Val__c = agencyName.Agency_Name_Type__c + ' - ' + agencyName.Name;
        }
        Update PCagencyNameList;
    }
    
    /*Agency Name changes for Bulk updates to Account and PC*/
    public void agencyNameUpdateAccPC(List<Agency_Name__c> nameList){
      Map<ID, String> PCNameIDMap = new Map<ID, String>();
      Map<ID, String> AgencyNameMap = new Map<ID, String>();
      Map<ID, String> AgencyLegalNameMap = new Map<ID, String>();
      Set<ID> AccIds = new Set<ID>();
      for(Agency_Name__c name_obj: nameList) {
        if(name_obj.Is_Display_Name__c) {
                           
          AgencyNameMap.put(name_obj.agency__c, name_obj.name);
          AccIds.add(name_obj.agency__c);
          
        }
        if(name_obj.agency_name_type__c == System.Label.Agency_Name_Type_Legal) {
          AgencyLegalNameMap.put(name_obj.agency__c, name_obj.name);
          AccIds.add(name_obj.agency__c);
        }
        PCNameIDMap.put(name_obj.id,name_obj.Agency_Name_Type__c + ' - ' + name_obj.name);
      }
      
      if(!AgencyNameMap.isEmpty() || !AgencyLegalNameMap.isEmpty()) {
        List<Account> AgencyList = new List<Account>();
        for(Account acc : [SELECT id, name, R_Agency_Legal_Name__c from Account where id IN :AccIds]) {
          if(acc.name != AgencyNameMap.get(acc.id) && AgencyNameMap.get(acc.id)!=null){
              
              System.debug('kanhu ** '+AgencyNameMap.get(acc.id));
            acc.name = AgencyNameMap.get(acc.id);
          }
          if(AgencyLegalNameMap.get(acc.id) <> null && acc.R_Agency_Legal_Name__c != AgencyLegalNameMap.get(acc.id)){
            acc.R_Agency_Legal_Name__c = AgencyLegalNameMap.get(acc.id);
          }
          AgencyList.add(acc);
        }
        if(!AgencyList.isEmpty())
            database.update(AgencyList,false);
            
      }
        
      List<Processing_Code__c> PCList = new List<Processing_Code__c>();
      for(Processing_Code__c pc_obj : [select Processing_Code_Name_Val__c,Processing_Code_Name__c FROM Processing_Code__c WHERE Processing_Code_Name__c IN :PCNameIDMap.keySet()]) {
        if(pc_obj.Processing_Code_Name_Val__c != PCNameIDMap.get(pc_obj.Processing_Code_Name__c)){      
            pc_obj.Processing_Code_Name_Val__c = PCNameIDMap.get(pc_obj.Processing_Code_Name__c);
            PCList.add(pc_obj);
        }
      }      
      if(!PCList.isEmpty()) {
        database.update(PCList,false);
      }    
    }   
    public boolean agencyNameDupCheck(List<Agency_Name__c> nameList){ 
        Map<ID,List<Agency_Name__c>> agencyNamesMap = new Map<ID,List<Agency_Name__c>>();
        Set<ID> agencyIDSet = new Set<ID>();
    
        for(Agency_Name__c nameRec : nameList){
            agencyIDSet.add(nameRec.Agency__c);
        }
    
        for(Agency_Name__c nameRec : [SELECT ID,Agency__c, Name, Is_Display_Name__c, Agency_Name_Type__c,Effective_Date__c 
                                                FROM Agency_Name__c WHERE Agency__c IN :agencyIDSet]){
            if(agencyNamesMap.containskey(nameRec.Agency__c)){
                List<Agency_Name__c> childNames = agencyNamesMap.get(nameRec.Agency__c);
                childNames.add(nameRec); 
                agencyNamesMap.put(nameRec.Agency__c,childNames);
            }
            else{
                List<Agency_Name__c> childNames = new List<Agency_Name__c>();
                childNames.add(nameRec); 
                agencyNamesMap.put(nameRec.Agency__c,childNames);
            }
       }
       
       if(!agencyNamesMap.isEmpty()) {
         for(Agency_Name__c nameRec : nameList){
           for(Agency_Name__c childName : agencyNamesMap.get(nameRec.Agency__c)){
               if(nameRec.ID != childName.ID && nameRec.Name == childName.Name){
                   return true;
               }    
            }        
          }   
       }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Trigger:**

```
trigger AgencyNameAfterTrigger on Agency_Name__c (after insert, after update,after delete) {

  FFIC_App_Settings__c s = FFIC_App_Settings__c.getInstance(UserInfo.GetUserID());
  if( null != s && s.Disable_Triggers__c ) return;
  
  COBM.from_trigger = 'AgencyNameAfterTrigger';
  COBM.add_stack();
  
  if(Trigger.IsDelete == False && !COBM.convert_prospect_to_location_flag && !COBM.create_new_account_flag){
    AgencyNameService agencyname = new AgencyNameService(Trigger.New[0]);

    if(trigger.new.size() == 1) {

      if(Trigger.isInsert || (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.oldMap.get(Trigger.New[0].ID).Is_Display_Name__c != Trigger.New[0].Is_Display_Name__c)){
        system.debug('display::'+Trigger.New[0].Is_Display_Name__c);
          if(Trigger.New[0].Is_Display_Name__c)
          agencyname.UncheckAllrecords();
        else
          agencyname.CheckLegalrecord();
      }

      TriggerRecursionHelper.setAlreadyCreated();

      if(trigger.new[0].Is_Display_Name__c || Trigger.new[0].agency_name_type__c == System.Label.Agency_Name_Type_Legal){
        Account accObj = [SELECT ID, Name, R_Agency_Legal_Name__c FROM Account WHERE ID = :trigger.new[0].Agency__c];
        if(trigger.new[0].Is_Display_Name__c && accObj.Name != trigger.new[0].Name){
          accObj.Name = trigger.new[0].Name;
        }
          system.debug('legel1::'+Trigger.new[0].agency_name_type__c);
        if(Trigger.new[0].agency_name_type__c == System.Label.Agency_Name_Type_Legal) { 
          accObj.R_Agency_Legal_Name__c = trigger.new[0].Name;
            
        }
          update accObj;
      } 
      
      TriggerRecursionHelper.unCheckCreated();
      
      if(trigger.New[0].Agency_Name_Type__c == System.Label.Agency_Name_Type_Legal  
       && (trigger.isInsert || (trigger.isupdate &&  Trigger.oldMap.get(Trigger.New[0].ID).Agency_Name_Type__c != Trigger.New[0].Agency_Name_Type__c )))
        agencyname.ChangePreviousLegaltoDBA();  
    }

//for Bulk updates to Account and PC
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
       System.debug(trigger.New[0].Agency_Name_Type__c+'** Kanhu **'+Trigger.new[0].name+' ** '+trigger.new[0].Is_Display_Name__c);
       agencyname.agencyNameUpdateAccPC(Trigger.new);
    }
  }
       
/*
Adding the below code snippet for Outbound Messaging - Agency Name
*/  
  COBM.from_trigger = 'AgencyNameAfterTrigger';
  COBM.parent_api_name = 'agency__c';
  Set<String> name_acc_ids = new Set<String>();
  
  if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
    for(Agency_Name__c name_obj: Trigger.new) {
      if(!COBM.s_acc_map.keyset().contains(name_obj.agency__c)) {
        name_acc_ids.add(name_obj.agency__c);
      }
    }
    if(name_acc_ids.size() > 0){
      for(Account acc_obj: [SELECT id, name, location_code__c, nationwide_code_2__c, active_status_effective_date__c, status__c, lastmodifieddate, recordtypename__c, personal_effective_status__c, commercial_effective_status__c, special_risk_effective_status__c, entertainment_effective_status__c, obsolete_effective_status__c, billingstate, Hierarchy_Type__c from Account where id IN :name_acc_ids]) {
        COBM.s_acc_map.put(acc_obj.id, acc_obj);
      }
    }
    COBM cobm_obj = new COBM(Trigger.new[0].getsObjectType(),Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
  } else {
    COBM cobm_obj = new COBM(Trigger.old[0].getsObjectType(),Trigger.old, 'DELETE');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the service class has a "bulk" interface and implementation where it can update many objects at once:

```
public void agencyNameUpdateAccPC(List<Agency_Name__c> nameList){
    ...
    if(!AgencyList.isEmpty())
        database.update(AgencyList,false);
    ...
}
```

but the trigger in many places only considers the first object. So separately from the governor limit error you report, it is very likely that the code produces the wrong results for the "bulk" case. Best to write a unit test for the bulk case to check that.

The trigger includes code that looks like an attempt to stop recursion where the trigger causes a change that causes the trigger to fire again:

```
TriggerRecursionHelper.setAlreadyCreated();
...
TriggerRecursionHelper.unCheckCreated();
```

But such code would normally follow a pattern such as this to have an effect:

```
if ( !TriggerRecursionHelper.isAlreadyCreated() ) {
    TriggerRecursionHelper.setAlreadyCreated();
    ...
    TriggerRecursionHelper.unCheckCreated();
}
```

Suggested steps:

1. Write the bulk case unit test for the trigger where multiple objects are inserted and updated and deleted; this test will fail
2. Fix the governor limit exception
3. Fix the logical error of only the first row being updated

This work could take days not hours.